# Javascript instanceof operator confusion

Tags: javascript

I've read about Javascript's `instanceof` operator and wanted to test it out. I've written this code:

```js
function first() {};
first.prototype.hello = function hello() {
 console.log("hello");
}

var second = {};


second.prototype = Object.create(first.prototype);

console.log(second instanceof first); //should've output true

second.hello();
```

This doesn't work as expected (by me). What I thought when writing this fragment:

`instanceof` takes a function (`first` in this case) as its right hand operand and an object as its left hand operand. Then it checks whether the given function's prototype appears in any part of the object's prototype chain. `first` is the function, `hello` is some function added to `first`'s prototype. `second`'s prototype is assigned a new object which has a prototype link to `first.prototype` so when `second instanceof first` is executed, it cannot find link to `first.prototype` object on `second` directly so it follows prototype link to `second.prototype` which has that link.

When I run this in Chrome [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Wuh.png) is the result:

> ```
> false
>
> Uncaught TypeError: second.hello is not a function
>   at main.js:13
> ```

Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: what's wrong with `second = new first()` - isn't that what you're trying to achieve? that patterns seems to be **trying** to subclass `first` as class `second` - but you're "doing it wrong"™

Comment: I don't think there's something wron with the constructor call version but this is not a practical code and it's written just to test what I learned.

Comment: Regarding images, please restrict them to things that really need to be images. We would vastly prefer if you just wrote in your question "`second instanceof first` returns false, and `second.hello()` yields `Uncaught TypeError: second.hello is not a function`", and indicated the corresponding line in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> second's prototype is assigned a new object

No, this part is wrong. You're creating a property *called* `"prototype"`, but that doesn't mean it is the object's actual prototype.

```
var second = {};
second.prototype = ...
```

is equivalent to

```
var second = { "prototype": ... };
```

but it's unrelated to inheritance.

Pretty much the only spot where a property called `"prototype"` is used is on constructor functions (such as your `first`), and even then it's not used as the prototype of the function itself; it's used as the prototype for any instances created later on from `new ThatFunction()`.

What you can do is

```
var second = new first;
// What this does:
//   - gets the object from first.prototype
//   - creates a new derived object, like Object.create(first.prototype)
//   - calls first(), passing the new object as 'this',
//      like first.call(Object.create(first.prototype))
//   - assigns the object returned from first() to second
//      (if first doesn't return an object, it automatically uses the new object created in step 2 instead)
```

or (mostly equivalent, but won't call `first`)

```
var second = Object.create(first.prototype);
```

Comment: So the actual prototype cannot be referenced with the expression `name.prototype`?

Comment: @BranTran That is correct. You can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) for that.

Comment: Just to anyone who may read this later: my mistake was not getting the meaning of the `prototype` property right. It (by default) exists only for functions and is a link to some other object. Using it for non-callable object's property is the same as just adding a new property on it (without any special meaning). Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `second.prototype`, use `second`

I've edited your code.

```js
function first() {};
first.prototype.hello = function hello() {
    console.log("hello");
}

var second = Object.create(first.prototype);

console.log(second instanceof first); //should've output true

second.hello();
```

Comment: I've actually tried this too and when it worked I was confused even more

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create ()` [returns the created object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which you need to store in `second` variable, not in `second.prototype`. It does not return an Object prototype, but the entire Object itself.

```
 var second = {}
 second = Object.create (first.prototype)
```